# How to get an element's name as a String inside a stream in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a List of file names `[1999-01-01, 1999-06-01, 1999-11-01]` and I would like to stream the list and access each file by its name in order to get some data from them.
The `getRatesFiles` gives me a list in the above format.

I would then like to use the name of each element, in order to feed it to `getRateAtDate` method that uses the date to read data from that file.
The final output should look like below:

```
"Date: 1999-01-01 Rate: 0.602941",
"Date: 1999-06-01 Rate: 0.621195",
"Date: 1999-11-01 Rate: 0.60824"
```

```
  public Double getRateAtDate(String symbol, String date) {
    RateListing rateListing = rlrReader.readRatesAtDate(date);
    throwExceptionIfSymbolNotFound(rateListing, symbol);

    return rateListing.rates().get(symbol);
  }



public String[] getRatesForYear(String symbol, String year) {

    List<String> listOfYearFiles = rlrReader.getRatesFiles();



List<String> stringsList = listOfYearFiles.stream()
            .filter(string -> string.startsWith(year))
            .sorted()
            .map(string -> getRateAtDate(symbol, ??)
            .map(string -> "Date: " + string)
            .toList();
```

Comment: replace `??` with `string`, then add the missing `)` at the end of that line? (Line: `.map(string -> getRateAtDate(symbol, ??)`).

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73843504/how-to-loop-through-elements-in-a-stream-and-return-a-value-in-java) constantly. Instead, if you have new information to add to it, edit the existing question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirement, you do not need to use `.map` twice. You can achieve it this way:

```
List<String> stringsList = listOfYearFiles.stream()
            .filter(string -> string.startsWith(year))
            .sorted()
            .map(string -> "Date: " + string + " Rate: " + getRateAtDate(symbol, string))
            .toList();
```

You can also join the elements to a single `String` as follows:

```
String output = listOfYearFiles.stream()
            .filter(string -> string.startsWith(year))
            .sorted()
            .map(string -> "Date: " + string + " Rate: " + getRateAtDate(symbol, string))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", \n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I unterstand that you want to compute the rate with getRateAtDate and collect both the date string and the rate double into an output string in the final streaming step. For this you need to pass along both the date string and the rate value to the last map step. *If you do not want to keep the map steps separated as you have them, better see Arvind Kumar Avinash's answer.*

First, pass your date string to the getDateAtRate function, so that you get the rate value. Second, you need to return a "tuple" of the date and the rate from that map step in order to have both available in the final step.

If you do not have a class for a combination (the tuple) of date and rate yet, you could create an inner class with two fields: one for the date string, one for the rate. Create an object of this class and return it from the map step that computes the rate. The string conversion step will get the object as input, and you can retrieve the two values from it to build the string.

```
static class RateAtDate {
    String date;
    Double rate;
    
    RateAtDate(Double r, String d) {
        rate = r;
        date = d;
    }
}

public String[] getRatesForYear(String symbol, String year) {
    ...
    List<String> stringsList = listOfYearFiles.stream()
        .filter(string -> string.startsWith(year))
        .sorted()
        .map(string -> new RateAtDate(getRateAtDate(symbol, string), string))
        .map(tuple -> "Date: " + tuple.date + " Rate: " + tuple.rate)
        .toList();
    ...
}
```

(If you prefer to use getters over direct field access and to make the fields private, please do. I did not want to make the example more verbose.)